# app stops while picking image from gallery into imageview

Tags: android

I have created a button that displays the options to take picture from camera, or to pick image from gallery. The image is directed to the `imageview` in the same activity. When the camera is used for getting image it works as expected, whereas the application stops after selecting the image from gallery rather than displaying it in the `imageview`. I am unable to figure out whether it's due to incorrect parsing of image to thumbnail or there's something missing in the code?

[image: This is the error]

**Main Activity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView vitb;
Button btcm;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_SELECT = 2;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vitb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btcm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cam);

    btcm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            selectImage();

        }

    });

}

private void selectImage() {



    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from 
Gallery","Cancel" };



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_SELECT);

            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }

        }

    });

    builder.show();

}



@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {

     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)bundle.get("data");
            vitb.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

}

}
```

Logcat:

```
01-21 22:53:56.345 20914-20914/com.dot.hackathon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: 
com.dot.hackathon, PID: 20914

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, 
request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { 
dat=content://media/external/images/media/44167 }} to activity 
{com.dot.hackathon/com.dot.hackathon.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri 
content://media/external/images/media/44167 from pid=20914, uid=10118 
requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3825)
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:164)
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1511)
                                                                   at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
                                                                   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run  
(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                                   at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
                                                                Caused by: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri 
content://media/external/images/media/44167 from pid=20914, uid=10118 
requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                   at 
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1559)
                                                                   at 
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel 
(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
                                                                   at 
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel 
(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
                                                                   at 
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                   at 
android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:527)
                                                                   at 
android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:471)
                                                                   at 
com.dot.hackathon.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:125)
                                                                   at 
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6309)
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3778)
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3825) 
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:164) 
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1511) 
                                                                   at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
                                                                   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
                                                                   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                   at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
                                                                   at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
01-21 22:53:56.445 20914-20914/com.dot.hackathon I/Process: Sending signal. 
PID: 20914 SIG: 9
01-21 22:53:56.445 20914-20914/com.dot.hackathon V/Process: killProcess 
[20914] 
Callers=com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler. 
uncaughtException:99 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690 <bottom of call stack>
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please

Comment: yes...i have edited the answer to add it.

Comment: you need runtime permission 6.0 and above version.and add your manifest file this permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

Add this permission in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

### FYI

**[Run Time Permissions Requesting](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)**

How to check Runtime permission please check below snippet of code

**Step1**

```
 private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Your_Activity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Step2**

```
 private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Your_Activity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Your_Activity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

**Step3**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Permission Granted");
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "Permission Denied.");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Henodi Welcome, Happy to help you.